# How to summarize responses in column to create a new response based on column headers?

Tags: r, if-statement, dplyr, tidyverse, multiple-columns

My data looks like this

```
ID<- c(1,2,3,4,5)
CV<- c("Detected", "Not Detected", "Detected", "Not Detected", "Detected")
RV<- c("Not Detected", "Detected", "Not Detected", "Detected", "Not Detected")
BP<- c("Detected", "Detected", "Not Detected", "Detected", "Detected")
FL<- c("Detected", "Detected", "Not Detected", "Detected", "Detected")

df<- data.frame(ID, CV, RV, BP, FL)
```

I would like to combine the "Detected" responses in each observation and create a new column that gives the column name of each detected response, like this

```
ID          CV                RV               BP              FL             Result
1           Detected          Not Detected     Detected        Detected       CV, BP, FL
2           Not Detected      Detected         Detected        Detected       RV, BP, FL
3           Detected          Not Detected     Not Detected    Not Detected   CV
4           Not Detected      Detected         Detected        Detected       RV, BP, FL
5           Detected          Not Detected     Detected        Detected       CV, BP, FL
```

Answer (score 1):

We could use `cur_column()` to identify the colnames in combination with the condition. Using `unite` will bring them together:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df %>% 
  mutate(across(-ID, ~case_when(. == "Detected" ~ cur_column()), .names = 'new_{col}')) %>%
  unite(Result, starts_with('new'), na.rm = TRUE, sep = ' ')
```

```
  ID           CV           RV           BP           FL   Result
1  1     Detected Not Detected     Detected     Detected CV BP FL
2  2 Not Detected     Detected     Detected     Detected RV BP FL
3  3     Detected Not Detected Not Detected Not Detected       CV
4  4 Not Detected     Detected     Detected     Detected RV BP FL
5  5     Detected Not Detected     Detected     Detected CV BP FL
```